# pykafka can not connect kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

When I use `pykafka` to connect `kafka` cluster via the following code:

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient
client = KafkaClient(hosts="10.0.0.101:9092")
```

I got the exception as following:

> raise Exception('Unable to connect to a broker to fetch metadata.')
>
> Exception: Unable to connect to a broker to fetch metadata.

But when I was using the command line such as:

`kafka-console-producer --broker-list 10.0.0.101:9092 --topic userCND`

it works fine but just gives me a warning message:

> WARN Property topic is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)

Comment: Please post your log if possible

Answer (score 2):

What version of Kafka are you using? `pykafka` currently only supports 0.8.2, not 0.9.0.

You may want to use the REST API instead. Learn more about the REST API here:

http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka-rest/docs/index.html

Comment: I'm not sure what pykafka's compatibility story is with 0.8.0. In general, it's safer to use the REST API for non-Java, non-C clients. The Java client is maintained by the Kafka community, the C client is very solid, and the REST API is maintained by Confluent. All other clients are maintained by 3rd parties and often have issues (at least from what I've seen).

Comment: PyKafka now supports Kafka brokers >=0.8.2. I can't speak to the compatibility story with 0.8.0 since I've never personally tested a broker that old, but I believe some functionality would be degraded. I recommend upgrading to a more recent Kafka broker version if this is still an issue.